# App is freezing in Samsung models after fixing for S+ Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, flags, android-workmanager, android-sdk-manager

I have an app, it makes crashes after updating to the sdk 31, I have fixed with adding the FLAG_IMMUTABLEs. But now the app not crashing. It shows the app freezing in widgets. Any thoughts on this.

```
Unable to start receiver .widget.WidgetProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: : Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Comment: You probably also need to update your widgets pending intents. Do you use setPendingIntentTemplate? If so, use FLAG_MUTABLE for that intent.

Comment: I have used like this. PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), getItemID(), actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);